# Get the value of a string inside a function

Tags: php, wordpress

so there's this function:

```
function rpress_get_service_types() {
  $service_types = array(
    'delivery'  => __( 'Delivery', 'restropress' ),
    'pickup'    => __( 'Pickup', 'restropress' )
  );
  return apply_filters( 'rpress_service_type', $service_types );
}
```

That I would like to get the value from. Let's say, is it `'delivery'` or `'pickup'`?

Then, I need to know if the product this whole code refers to is set as a `'pickup'` or `'delivery'` - each product is assigned to only one of these two values.

So, before I even try to validate if it matches one of these two values, I thought I'd print it out in the email I send as a test to myself... to see if it works.

The code below returns the value `The order #2262 is ready for delivery!Arraytest` on the emails I receive as a test:

```
function send_customer_purchase_notification_ready( $payment_id, $new_status ) {

    $pickup_or_delivery = rpress_get_service_types( $service_types );
    $order_status = rpress_get_option( $new_status );
    $check_notification_enabled = isset( $order_status['enable_notification'] ) ? true : false;

    if ( !empty( $payment_id ) && $check_notification_enabled && $new_status !== 'pending' && $new_status == 'ready' ) {                  
        $message = 'The order #' .$payment_id. ' is ready for delivery!' .$pickup_or_delivery. 'test';
        $to = 'email@gmail.com';
        $subject = "READY FOR PICKUP";
        $headers = ''; 
        //Here put your Validation and send mail
        $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
    }
}
add_action( 'rpress_update_order_status', 'send_customer_purchase_notification_ready' , 10, 2 );
```

As you can see, I placed the variable inside `$message = 'The order #' .$payment_id. ' is ready for delivery!' .$pickup_or_delivery. 'test';`

To sumarize: this code displays the words `Array`.

I've tried moving things arround for many hours and I feel I'm hitting myself against the wall. Any ideas?

Comment: Add => `$pickup_or_delivery['delivery']` for delievery AND `$pickup_or_delivery['pickup']` for pickup

Comment: Let me know if there is something more dynamic you are trying to do with this email and service. I will post a detailed solution for you.

Comment: hey I tried this like so (after `$check_notification_enabled`) but I don't get an email with this addition: `$pickup_or_delivery['delivery'];
 $pickup_or_delivery['pickup'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code to get "Service type" :

```
$service_type = rpress_get_service_type( $payment_id );
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the `rpress_get_service_types()` will return an *array* so the `$pickup_or_delivery` is an *array*.

You can not concatenate the string `The order #2262 is ready for delivery!..` with an *array*.
you should convert the array to string if you want, by using [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) or get the buffer content with [ob_get_clean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

```
$pickup_or_delivery = rpress_get_service_types();

// get the imploded version
$pickup_or_delivery = implode(',', $pickup_or_delivery);

// or get the buffer content
ob_start();
print_r($pickup_or_delivery);
$pickup_or_delivery = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: OK! adding your suggestion returned the values "Pickup,Delivery" on the email so the data's coming through! How can I filter "Delivery" only items? I tried this but I don't get an email.. so something must be wrong:

`if ( !empty( $payment_id ) && $check_notification_enabled && $new_status !== 'pending' && $new_status == 'ready' && $pickup_or_delivery !== 'pickup' && $pickup_or_delivery == 'delivery' ) {`
Also tried with `'Pickup'` and `'Delivery'` (respecting upper and lower case) but I still don't get an email, which leads me to believe this part of the code is buggy

Comment: i'm actually trying to retrieve the value for this specific item.. it should either return `'Pickup'` or `'Delivery'`, since an item cannot have the two at the same time. Does this make sense?

Comment: @MarcioVieyra yeah, i am just trying to answer your summary about the "code displays the word Array" :). If you want to receive the filtered value, you have to update your function to allow some argument, e.g `rpress_get_service_types( $type ){` and return the filtered one `return apply_filters( 'rpress_service_type', isset( $service_types[ $type ] ) ? $service_types[ $type ] : '' );`

and update the function call with the correct argument e.g `$pickup_or_delivery = rpress_get_service_types( 'delivery );`

no need to implode $pickup_or_delivery in this case